# Does using noipa or optnone attributes remove the need for asm("")

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization, clang

In GCC, one can use the `noipa` attribute to disable inter-procedural optimiations. Similarly, in Clang, `optnone` can be used to disable all optimization.

However, GCC's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) for `noinline` states that `asm("")` is required to make sure that the compiler doesn't optimize away the function call completely. Quoting:

> If the function does not have side effects, there are optimizations other than inlining that cause function calls to be optimized away, although the function call is live.

My question is, if we use `noipa` or `optnone`, do we still need to add this `asm` statement to make sure that the GCC and Clang respectively would not optimize away function calls?